# Next and Previous buttons then display record SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to move to and display the next query result, the examples I have seen refer to things like count = 1 or get all records, but can't work out how they are implemented.

I am able to display the first record fine, but when trying to `moveToNext` I end up at the last result, and `moveToPrev` does nothing. (I'm guessing this has to do with the count variable I've read about)

DBHelper.Java

```
    public Cursor PL_get_Record(String pldescription, SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase) {
      String selection = PLDESCRIPTION + " LIKE ?";
      String[] selection_args = {
        "%" + pldescription + "%"
      };
      Cursor c = sqlitedatabase.query(PLTABLE_NAME, PL_All_Cols, selection, selection_args, null, null, null);
      return c;
    }
```

MainActivity.Java - MoveToNext button

```
public void btn_ParamNext(View view) {
  dbhelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
  sqlitedatabase = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor c = dbhelper.get_Record(Desc, sqlitedatabase);
  while (c.moveToNext()) {
    DisplayData(c);
  }
  c.close();
}
```

MainActivity.Java - MoveToPrevious button

```
public void ParamPrev(View view) {
  dbhelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
  sqlitedatabase = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
  Cursor c = dbhelper.get_Record(Desc, sqlitedatabase);
  while (c.moveToPrevious()) {
    DisplayData(c);
  }
  c.close();
}
```

Other examples I have seen refer to RawQuery, which I have hot been able to get to work at all.

Any help or examples would be very appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

@Frank , thanks for your reply. I have tried taking your advice, but I'm obviously not understanding properly, my code it now as follows.

DbHelper.java

```
public Cursor PL_get_Record (String pldescription, SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase) {
String selection = PLDESCRIPTION+" LIKE ?";
String [] selection_args = {"%"+pldescription+"%"};
Cursor cursor = sqlitedatabase.query(PLTABLE_NAME, PL_All_Cols, selection, selection_args, null, null, null);
return cursor; }
```

OnClickListener with btnFirstRec, btnNext & btnPrev buttons

```
   private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnFirstRec:
            dbhelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
            sqlitedatabase = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = dbhelper.PL_get_Record(Desc, sqlitedatabase);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                DisplayData(c);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.btnNext:
            if (c != null && !c.isAfterLast()) {
                c.moveToNext();
                DisplayData(c);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.btnPrev:
            if (c != null && !c.isBeforeFirst()) {
                c.moveToPrevious();
                DisplayData(c);
            }
            break;
    }
} 
};
```

I am now getting an error
`Variable c might not have been initialized`

If I change the btnNext and btnPrev to

```
            dbhelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
            sqlitedatabase = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = dbhelper.PL_get_Record(Desc, sqlitedatabase);
            if (c != null && !c.isAfterLast()) {
                c.moveToNext();
                DisplayData(c);
            }
            break;
```

I end up with

`variable c is already defined in method onClick(View)`

not sure what else to try, Please help.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein 
How do I stop the looping? 
I have tried break and return but neither worked.

Comment: I added an answer. See if it helps you.

Comment: You edited your question. I see you didn't understand my answer in full. You must get the cursor OUTSIDE the Click listener. This is why you get `variable c is already defined in method onClick(View)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are loping through the records.

If you're on the first record (and when you retrieve a record set **you aren't**, until you move to the first or next record), then you are looping to the last record and only get the last display.

If you're on the first record (and when you retrieve a record set **you aren't**, until you move to the first or next record), then you stop at the first iteration, since you can't move before the first record.

What I would do is to rewrite your button click listeners to simply step up or down a position once you got the cursor.

So, let's say tou retrieve the cursor like this:

```
// You have to change your dbhelper method name to match - atually there's an extra "PL_"
Cursor c = dbhelper.get_Record(Desc, sqlitedatabase);
if (c != null)
{
    c.moveToFirst(); // position on the first record, as soon as you get the cursor
}
```

Then in your click listeners simply do (btnNext)

```
if (c != null && !c.isAfterLast)
{
    c.moveToNext()
}
```

or (btnPRev)

```
if (c != null && !c.isBeforeFirst)
{
    c.moveToPrevious()
}
```

As adequate.

**[EDIT]**

You edited your question, but I see you didn't understand my answer in full.
You must get the cursor OUTSIDE the Click listener.

This is why you get `variable c is already defined in method onClick(View)`

So, move this part

```
dbhelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
sqlitedatabase = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = dbhelper.PL_get_Record(Desc, sqlitedatabase);
```

before the `onClick()` method.

Also, you can move the line

```
DisplayData(c);
```

after the `switch()`, instead of repeating it in all cases.
It has to be executed anyway.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried taking your advice, but I'm obviously not understanding properly, my code it now as follows.

Comment: Thanks Mate, got it working. Have a lot of learning to do, including how this site works. ;-)